# Threading with web.py and memcached

Tags: python, multithreading, memcached, web.py

I am using memchached with web.py to store sessions (as I do not want them to be stored on a disk due to speed and scalability issues).  I am using the code from [here](http://www.rawsontetley.org/ref_webpymemcache.html) with pylibmc.

However, it keeps breaking.  I think it may be the multiple threads breaking it.  Its definitely memcached as using a disk store for the sessions works fine, but with the custom store, it just hangs.

Is it possible that threads are the issue here?  How would one resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved via creating a new mc object for each request.  Thus the `MemCacheStore` looks like this:

```
class MemCacheStore(web.session.Store):
                ...
    def __contains__(self, key):
        mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
        return mc.get(key) != None
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
        return mc.get(key)
               ...
```